# Select option is selecting the same value

Tags: html

I have a select option in the table, When i am selecting yes in html file, then it is selecting No value and If i am selecting No then also selecting No value,  dont understand why this is happening. please help.

```
<tr>
    <td> 24x7</td>
     <td>
         <select name="select10" id="Fvalue">
             <option value="No">No</option>
             <option value="Yes">Yes</option>   
         </select>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" id="Gvalue" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: The markup you provided should work fine. The problem must be somewhere else.

Comment: nothing crazy going on there. and its working fine => http://jsfiddle.net/Ux5aT/

Comment: I am calling that using the below document.getElementById("Fvalue").value; and checked using alert box, then i find it is selecting the same value

Comment: @user178900: Can you provide a complete example which demonstrates the problem, instead of just describing it?

Comment: I cant do that because its a lenthy code